# Satisfy flake8 using the following example

Tags: python, flake8

I have a very simple expression below. I am checking each character of a password to ensure it has at least one of the below special characters. However, Flake8 registers the example as bad. How can I address this within Flake8?

W605 invalid escape sequence '!'

W605 invalid escape sequence '$'

W605 invalid escape sequence '^'

W605 invalid escape sequence '*'

W605 invalid escape sequence '('

W605 invalid escape sequence ')'

W605 invalid escape sequence '+'

W605 invalid escape sequence '['

W605 invalid escape sequence ']'

```
def clean_password(self):
    special_characters = "[~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+{}\":;'\[\]]"
    if len(self.data["password"]) < 8:
        raise ValidationError("Password length must be greater than 8 characters.")
    if not any(char.isdigit() for char in self.data["password"]):
        raise ValidationError("Password must contain at least 1 digit.")
    if not any(char.isalpha() for char in self.data["password"]):
        raise ValidationError("Password must contain at least 1 letter.")
    if not any(char in special_characters for char in self.data["password"]):
        raise ValidationError("Password must contain at least 1 special character.")
    return self.data["password"]
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the special characters? Like `\!`? Why not just `!`?

Comment: It was an example I found. I welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flake8 is complaining because in your string of `special_characters` you are escaping some characters that do not need to be escaped.

In your list the only character that needs to be escaped is the double quotes (`"`), so you can just do:

```py
special_characters = "~!@#$%^&*()_+{}\":;'[]"
```

> NOTE: I also removed the first and last squared brakets as they were duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I solved as follows:

```
def password_check(password):
    """
    Verify the strength of 'password'
    Returns a dict indicating the wrong criteria
    A password is considered strong if:
        8 characters length or more
        1 digit or more
        1 symbol or more
        1 uppercase letter or more
        1 lowercase letter or more
    """

    # calculating the length
    length_error = len(password) < 8

    # searching for digits
    digit_error = re.search(r"\d", password) is None

    # searching for uppercase
    uppercase_error = re.search(r"[A-Z]", password) is None

    # searching for lowercase
    lowercase_error = re.search(r"[a-z]", password) is None

    # searching for symbols
    symbol_error = re.search(r"[ !#$%&'()*+,-./[\\\]^_`{|}~"+r'"]', password) is None

    # overall result
    password_ok = not ( length_error or digit_error or uppercase_error or lowercase_error or symbol_error )

    return {
        'password_ok' : password_ok,
        'length_error' : length_error,
        'digit_error' : digit_error,
        'uppercase_error' : uppercase_error,
        'lowercase_error' : lowercase_error,
        'symbol_error' : symbol_error,
    }


    def clean_password(self):

        userpassword = password_check(self.data["password"])
        
        if (userpassword['length_error']):
            raise ValidationError("Password length must be at least 8 characters.")
        elif(userpassword['digit_error']):
            raise ValidationError("Password must contain at least 1 digit.")
        elif(userpassword['uppercase_error']):
            raise ValidationError("Password must contain at least 1 uppercase character.")
        elif(userpassword['lowercase_error']):
            raise ValidationError("Password must contain at least 1 lowercase character.")
        elif(userpassword['symbol_error']):
            raise ValidationError("Password must contain at least 1 special character.")
        else:
            return self.data["password"]
```